# Разные формы глаголов в одном предложении

Tags: синтаксис, глаголы

Предложение:

*Он сказал, что остаётся директором и продолжит менять политику компании.*

"Остаётся" и "продолжит" могут стоять в одном предложении?

Comment: Остается директором и продолжит менять / Остаётся директором, меняющим (обновляющим)